# How to create a duplicate WordPress site running on localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I am running a local copy of WordPress and simply want to duplicate the whole folder. When I copy all the files into another folder and run it on localhost, i get a 404 error. Also the new folder i've pasted into is 10mb larger. What exactly is happening?

I assume the 404 error is something to do with the database, but I expect everything to be the same. The config file is pointing to correct DB etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix the duplicate wp site not showing on localhost. in wpconfig, i needed to add:
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/duplicatesite');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/duplicatesite');
not sure why thats not needed on the original site, or why when copying a folder, it increases the size, but hey. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wordpress duplicator](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) for copy site correctly. Otherwise, you need manually fix some of the links in the db.